# How can apply filter to the following code?

Tags: arrays, filter

```
{
"cities":[
    {"name":"bangalore","hotels":["park","leela","mac"]},
    {"name":"chennai","hotels":["shang","mang","bang"]},
    {"name":"hyderabad","hotels":["taj","oberai","ibis"]}
    ]}
```

I have been trying cities.filter("bangalore"), to retrieve the hotels related to bangalore, but i am not able to recieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter(obj => obj.name === 'bangalore')` to get the object with name `bangalore` and if the name can be `Bangalore` with uppercase character then you can use `filter(obj => obj.name.toLowerCase() === 'bangalore')`.

```js
var data = {
"cities":[
    {"name":"bangalore","hotels":["park","leela","mac"]},
    {"name":"chennai","hotels":["shang","mang","bang"]},
    {"name":"hyderabad","hotels":["taj","oberai","ibis"]}
    ]};
    
var res = data.cities.filter(obj => obj.name === 'bangalore');
console.log(res);
```

You can also use a `forEach()` loop to get the hotels array only that is related to `bangalore`

```js
var data = {
  "cities":[
    {"name":"Bangalore","hotels":["park","leela","mac"]},
    {"name":"chennai","hotels":["shang","mang","bang"]},
    {"name":"bangalore","hotels":["taj","oberai","ibis"]}
  ]};

var hotels = [];
data.cities.forEach((obj) => {
  if(obj.name.toLowerCase() === 'bangalore'){
    hotels.push(...obj.hotels);

  }
});
console.log(hotels);
```